# What kind of perfume is it? / What perfume is it?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> **What kind of perfume** is it?
>
> **What perfume** is it?

Am I right that the first question asks about the characteristic (or some additional information) of perfume, not only name of it but the second question asks exactly (and only) the name of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are.The first sentence asks about the "kind" (=type) of perfume. This presumably asks for one of a set of categories into which perfume is normally sorted.

The second sentence asks for the name, probably the brand name, of the perfume.